# gmaps4rails is not showing map

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

in view

```
<div style='width: 800px;'>
  <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
</script>
```

in application.js

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers([
    {
      "lat": 0,
      "lng": 0,
      "picture": {
        "url": "http://people.mozilla.com/~faaborg/files/shiretoko/firefoxIcon/firefox-32.png",
        "width":  32,
        "height": 32
      },
      "infowindow": "hello!"
    }
  ]);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
```

also include underscore.js
in header

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.18&sensor=false&client=&key=&libraries=geometry&language=&hl=&region="></script> 
<script src="//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js"></script>
```

but still map is not showing.....
can any body help me ..these are two errors is console

```
ReferenceError: google is not defined
ReferenceError: handler is not defined
```

Comment: problem is solved i put application.js code directly in my view and problem solve...

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad thing to put your js code directly in your view. Try solving this problem different way - put all you "map code" in document.ready handler like so

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // put your code for initialising map  
});
```

Also in your view wrap your code in handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
});
</script>
```

It should work

Comment: if you are ok with that you can leave it as is, but I would suggest making it "right way". If you want, I can try to help you. Would be great to see your whole application.js file